# Createjs - Tweenjs doesn't work with Bitmap

Tags: javascript

I have an example, i want to create animation with easel.js Bitmap but it seems not working. In this project, i use preload.js to load image; crop card in cards picture; create Bitmap object and try to animate this bitmap by using tween.js Anyone can help me. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/CanvasLib/easeljs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/CanvasLib/preloadjs-0.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/CanvasLib/soundjs-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/CanvasLib/tweenjs-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="CanvasDemo" width ="1024" height="768" style="border:1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>

<script>
    var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(),
        stage = new createjs.Stage("CanvasDemo"),
        text = new createjs.Text("Welcome to canvas demo!", "40px Bold Aria"),
        image = {},
        card = {};

    stage.addChild(text);
    //stage.autoClear = false;

    queue.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    queue.loadManifest([
        { id: "myImage", src: "Images/card.png" }
    ]);

    function handleComplete() {
        image = queue.getResult("myImage");
        card = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
        card.sourceRect = new createjs.Rectangle(56, 74, 56, 74);
        stage.addChild(card);
        createjs.Tween.get(card).to({ x: 600, y: 1000 }, createjs.Ease.linear);

        createjs.Ticker.addListener(this);
    }

    function tick() {
        text.x += 5;

        if (text.x >= 1024) {
            text.x = 0;
        }

        text.y = 50 + Math.cos(text.x * 0.1) * 10;

        text.color = createjs.Graphics.getHSL(360 * Math.random(), 50, 50);
        stage.update();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine - except you skipped the "duration" parameter on the Tween.to call (and instead specified the ease, which is the 3rd parameter). This makes it a 0-duration tween, which ends up off-stage (so you never see it).

Try this instead:

`createjs.Tween.get(card).to({ x: 600, y: 1000 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.linear);`